# I want to integrate ADFS with my spring web application . Can anyone help me with this

Tags: spring, spring-security, adfs

I want to integrate ADFS with my spring web application . Can anyone help me with this. My application has spring-security authentication. Now i have to integrate ADFS for one of my client . All suggestion are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS supports SAML, so an option would be to integrate the Spring-saml module into your application https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/ and configure ADFS adequately